# Adjusting features of a pgf plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the pgf plots below, where it doesn't appear well. I wish to

1. put closer the "Solving Time(ms)" and y axis,
2. put the font size smaller 
   how should i do it?

There is also a problem for cramping up the number in the right chart, is there a way not to display every number so that the number do not cramping up?

```
\documentclass[9pt]{sig-alternate}
% GRAPHICS
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
every axis/.append style={
font=\sffamily,
  width=6.5cm,
    height=4.9cm
}
}
\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\scriptsize
 \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{semilogyaxis}[title=\textbf{ Dataset 1},
    legend pos=outer north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        xtick={50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500},
    scaled ticks=false,
    log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
        axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
        axis line style=-,
        minor tick style={draw=none},
        enlargelimits,
        ylabel = Solving Time (ms),
        xlabel = Service Class Size
]
\addplot plot coordinates{(50,77)(100,81)(150,109)(200,155)(250,112)(300,139)(350,175)(400,214)(450,206)(500,228)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(50,10)(100,1)(150,2)(200,2)(250,1)(300,1)(350,1)(400,2)(450,1)(500,1)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(50,2)(100,2)(150,2)(200,2)(250,2)(300,1)(350,1)(400,2)(450,1)(500,1)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(50,3)(100,1)(150,1)(200,1)(250,1)(300,1)(350,1)(400,1)(450,1)(500,1)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(50,5)(100,1)(150,2)(200,1)(250,1)(300,1)(350,1)(400,1)(450,1)(500,1)};
\legend{$a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$}
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\scriptsize
 \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{semilogyaxis}[title=\textbf{ Dataset 2},
    legend pos=outer north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        xtick={500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500,4000,4500,5000},
    scaled ticks=false,
    log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
        axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
        axis line style=-,
        minor tick style={draw=none},
        enlargelimits,
        ylabel = Solving Time (ms),
        xlabel = Service Class Size
]
\addplot plot coordinates{(500,35)(1000,1048)(1500,1668)(2000,2309)(2500,2918)(3000,3965)(3500,5008)(4000,5569)(4500,5833)(5000,6680)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(500,855)(1000,1613)(1500,1878)(2000,2228)(2500,2738)(3000,2480)(3500,2512)(4000,3263)(4500,3746)(5000,4676)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(500,80)(1000,90)(1500,62)(2000,77)(2500,54)(3000,49)(3500,33)(4000,45)(4500,34)(5000,68)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(500,101)(1000,633)(1500,302)(2000,151)(2500,138)(3000,35)(3500,41)(4000,57)(4500,20)(5000,42)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(500,20)(1000,66)(1500,79)(2000,74)(2500,81)(3000,45)(3500,57)(4000,45)(4500,27)(5000,17)};
\legend{$a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$}
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the output from the code below

[image]

I changed a few things, which you'll see I've tagged with `% new bit`

- I moved `\pgfplotsset` into the preamble
- I removed some of the surplus packages- `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, `pgf`, and `graphicx`, so there's no need to load them explicitly
- I removed `\scriptsize` from each individual picture, and put it in `\pgfplotsset` so that the changes are global
- I removed `textbf` from your individual titles and created a style in `pgfplotsset` in the preamble (this will ease global changes in the future)
- I removed `[font=\sffamily]` from `\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]` as it is specified globally in the preamble now
- I changed `xtick` in each of the pictures, to make the labels a little less cluttered
- I moved the `ylabel` closer to the axis using `ylabel shift=-2pt`, which requires `compat=1.3` or newer
- I added a `%` after your first `\end{minipage}`; this is very important as it removes the additional space that a `minipage` inserts, and removes the `Overfull hbox` warning that you got

**Code**

```
\documentclass[9pt]{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.3,
    xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    every axis/.append style={
        font=\sffamily,
        label style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily}, % new bit
        legend style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily},% new bit
        title style={font=\bfseries\sffamily}, % new bit
        width=6.5cm,
        height=4.9cm,
        ylabel shift=-2pt, % new bit
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{semilogyaxis}[title=Dataset 1,
                legend pos=outer north east,
                legend style={draw=none},
                xtick={50,150,...,500}, % new bit
                scaled ticks=false,
                log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
                axis x line=bottom,
                axis y line=left,
                axis line style=-,
                minor tick style={draw=none},
                enlargelimits,
                ylabel = Solving Time (ms),
                xlabel = Service Class Size
                ]
                \addplot plot coordinates{(50,77)(100,81)(150,109)(200,155)(250,112)(300,139)(350,175)(400,214)(450,206)(500,228)};
                \addplot plot coordinates{(50,10)(100,1)(150,2)(200,2)(250,1)(300,1)(350,1)(400,2)(450,1)(500,1)};
                \addplot plot coordinates{(50,2)(100,2)(150,2)(200,2)(250,2)(300,1)(350,1)(400,2)(450,1)(500,1)};
                \addplot plot coordinates{(50,3)(100,1)(150,1)(200,1)(250,1)(300,1)(350,1)(400,1)(450,1)(500,1)};
                \addplot plot coordinates{(50,5)(100,1)(150,2)(200,1)(250,1)(300,1)(350,1)(400,1)(450,1)(500,1)};
                \legend{$a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$}
            \end{semilogyaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}% new bit
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{semilogyaxis}[title=Dataset 2,
                legend pos=outer north east,
                legend style={draw=none},
                xtick={500,1500,...,4500}, % new bit
                scaled ticks=false,
                log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
                axis x line=bottom,
                axis y line=left,
                axis line style=-,
                minor tick style={draw=none},
                enlargelimits,
                ylabel = Solving Time (ms),
                xlabel = Service Class Size
                ]
                \addplot plot coordinates{(500,35)(1000,1048)(1500,1668)(2000,2309)(2500,2918)(3000,3965)(3500,5008)(4000,5569)(4500,5833)(5000,6680)};
                \addplot plot coordinates{(500,855)(1000,1613)(1500,1878)(2000,2228)(2500,2738)(3000,2480)(3500,2512)(4000,3263)(4500,3746)(5000,4676)};
                \addplot plot coordinates{(500,80)(1000,90)(1500,62)(2000,77)(2500,54)(3000,49)(3500,33)(4000,45)(4500,34)(5000,68)};
                \addplot plot coordinates{(500,101)(1000,633)(1500,302)(2000,151)(2500,138)(3000,35)(3500,41)(4000,57)(4500,20)(5000,42)};
                \addplot plot coordinates{(500,20)(1000,66)(1500,79)(2000,74)(2500,81)(3000,45)(3500,57)(4000,45)(4500,27)(5000,17)};
                \legend{$a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$}
            \end{semilogyaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

As a final comment- there are a lot of features that common to both plots, such as

```
            scaled ticks=false,
            log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            axis line style=-,
            minor tick style={draw=none},
            enlargelimits,
```

If these are true in every single plot that you draw in this document, then you might like to consider putting these into your global `pgfplotsset` as well.

In general, try and use `styles` where ever possible- it eases both code readability and global changes, and is one of the many reasons to use `tikz` :)

Comment: +1 yticklabels are still in serif fonts. Four digit numbers shouldn't have a thousand separator.